# Serilog with Sentry and .net core 2.1 in a Linux docker container is not writing logs

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, serilog, sentry

We are using *Serilog* and *Sentry* with `.Net core 2.1`, we would like to send logs to our Sentry server. It all works fine locally and even when I run `Docker run "my-docker-path"` from local, it writes to the log. But as soon as we deploy it to a Docker with Linux under the hood, it just stops working. The firewall is open and we have access to the Sentry from the Docker container. The serilog.sinks.console works fine and it worked before with NLog in the same environment. Any ideas?

Update: I tried it with the SentrySDK (without Serilog) and it works fine too.

**My installed Nuget Packages**

- `Sentry.Protocol`
- `Sentry.Serilog`
- `Serilog.AspNetCore`
- `Serilog.Sinks.Console`
- `Sentry.Serilog`

**Program.cs**

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseKestrel()                
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseEnvironment(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") ?? "Development")
            .UseUrls(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_URLS") ?? "http://*:5000/")
            .UseSerilog(
                (hostingContext, loggerConfiguration) =>
                    loggerConfiguration
                        .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                        .MinimumLevel.Information()
                        .WriteTo.Console()
                        .WriteTo.Sentry(s => {
                            s.MinimumBreadcrumbLevel = LogEventLevel.Debug;
                            s.MinimumEventLevel = LogEventLevel.Error;
                            s.Dsn = "MyDsnAddress";
                        }))
            .Build();

        host.Run();
    }
}
```

Comment: first of all go with atleast .net core 3.1. you will find most example with this version or 5.0

Comment: If this works locally but not with Docker it must be related to the your infrastructure setup. Try to set the SDK in debug mode with `s.Debug = true` to get some insight on what it's doing.